# Sticky Position: Header scrolled away after a while

Tags: html, css, scroll, position, sticky

On my website I have made the `<nav>` stick to the top, but it only sticks a few seconds / pixels when I scroll down, then it gets scrolled away, please see the code snippet below and scroll down. I want the `nav` to stick to the top any time when scroll down, except when the `<header>` is visible.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Danis Website</title>
        <link href="reset.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header>
                <h1>Danis Website</h1>
            </header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="rezepte.html">Rezepte</a></li>
                    <li><a href="zutaten.html">Zutaten</a></li>   
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <main>
                Main Main Main<!-- In the code snippet below here are more lines of Text, here if have omitted the lines for better readability.

            </main>
            <footer>
                Footer
            </footer>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body, html{
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #aaa;
}


#wrapper{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: fuchsia;
}

header{
    flex: 0 0 50px;
    background-color: #888;
    text-align: center;
    position: sticky;
    top: 100px;
}

nav{
    flex: 0 0 50px;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    height: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border-left: 2px solid #aaa;
}

nav ul li:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}

nav ul li a{
    color: white;   
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #888;
}

main{
    flex: 1;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

footer{
    flex: 0 0 50px;
    background-color: #888;
}

#list{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#list-item{
    flex: 0 1 300px;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid dodgerblue;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#list-item-img{
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#list-item-text{
    flex: 1;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#list-item-text p {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body, html{
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #aaa;
}


#wrapper{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: fuchsia;
}

header{
    flex: 0 0 50px;
    background-color: #888;
    text-align: center;
}

nav{
    flex: 0 0 50px;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    height: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border-left: 2px solid #aaa;
}

nav ul li:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}

nav ul li a{
    color: white;   
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #888;
}

main{
    flex: 1;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

footer{
    flex: 0 0 50px;
    background-color: #888;
}

#list{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#list-item{
    flex: 0 1 300px;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid dodgerblue;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#list-item-img{
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#list-item-text{
    flex: 1;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#list-item-text p {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header>
                <h1>Danis Website</h1>
            </header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="rezepte.html">Rezepte</a></li>
                    <li><a href="zutaten.html">Zutaten</a></li>   
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <main>
                Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main 
              Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main Main 
            </main>
            <footer>
                Footer
            </footer>
            </div>
```

**Edit:** I'm using Firefx 37.0.2 on Arch Linux

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe it might be because of `height: 100%` on your `body`. When your content is too long, the `body` doesn't wrap around the entire content instead it just inherits the browser viewport height. Hence when you scroll past the bottom of the `body`, the `nav` stops sticking.

*On a side note though I don't think you should be using `position: sticky` just yet. It has less than browser 20% support. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky*

**Solution:** substitute `height: 100%;` to `min-height: 100%;` in #wrapper. When just removing `height: 100%;` the page is smaller than the viewport on pages where the content doesn't fill the viewport

Comment: That seems to be  the problem, the point where it scroll away is right at the end of the viewport. I know that it is not widely supported, but as far as I know in other browser it's just ignored, so there no problem

Comment: I am implementing the same for horizontal scroll. I am not having the width 100% property. Even if i set min-width: 100%, still the stick element is getting scrolled away. Can someone help me with this? @danielr1996

Comment: This answer strike to my point. Nice man.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same sticky problem here.

And as DigitalDouble said, it is the content height problem,
but not only caused in body

I found it in my JavaScript code...

> Change
> $(contentElement).style.***height*** = "99px";
>
> to
> $(contentElement).style.***minHeight*** = "99px";

I hope it helps. =)